# how to initialize uicollectionview with particular item(indexPath)

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a good looking gridView on firstViewController and also having the UIcollectionview on SecondViewController ,  now my issue is ,  if i select the forth item in GridView means then the Collectionview should show the forth item intead of Zero item  (now the collectionview is  shows from 0th index) !

my didSelectItemAtIndexPath: which is on FirstViewController, here i got the NSInteger value to pass to secondviewcontroller,

```
- (void)gridView:(KKGridView *)theGridView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(KKIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSInteger globalIndex = ( indexPath.section * numberOfThumbnails ) + indexPath.index;
..............................
}
```

my cellForItemAtIndexPath:  which is on secondViewController,

```
(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    itemData =[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *finalPath = [FileUtils findImagePath:[itemData filename]];

    CollectionCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:finalPath]];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is either scroll to the that particular item using

```
 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

Or select that item

```
 selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:
```